# Unable to see "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC" driver in SSIS

Tags: mysql, ssis, odbc, oledb

I am using VS2013 and SQL Server 2014. I am unable to see "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC" in OLEDB driver list in SSIS.

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you are searching under OLE DB connections.

Try under connection manager and add a new connection:
[image]

Comment: I still cannot see the drivers